# Визуализация наложения рамы на фото

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю калькулятор для сайта багетной мастерской. При выборе багета (рамы, в которую будет вставлена картина), нужно фото этого багета накладывать на загруженное пользователем изображение (его я подгружаю через FileReader). Вопрос: каким образом это сделать? Использовать ли Canvas или без него можно обойтись?

```js
$('.input_image').on('change', function(event) {
  if (FileReader) {
    var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var imgtag = document.getElementById("myimage");
    imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;

    reader.onload = function(event) {
      imgtag.src = event.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
  } else {
    console.log('FileReader не поддерживается в этом браузере!')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="input_image">
<img id="myimage" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Показывайте код, который у вас есть.

Comment: добавила код выше

Comment: Теперь еще бы хорошо примеры рамок)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле вариантов решения может быть много (включая изыски с border-image), но самый простой вариант, как мне кажется, - это отображать загруженную картинку в div'е, у которого багеты будут выступать в качестве фона:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('[type="file"]').change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

$('.clear').click(function(){
  $('[type="file"]').val('');
  $('.upload').attr('src', '');
  $('[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
})
```

```css
.picture {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.upload {
  max-width: 500px;
}
[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
[for="one"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WefMa.jpg');
}
[for="two"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSXK.jpg');
}
[for="three"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1FmU.png');
}
#one:checked ~ .picture {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WefMa.jpg');
}
#two:checked ~ .picture {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSXK.jpg');
}
#three:checked ~ .picture {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1FmU.png');
}
.clear {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="baget" id="one" />
<input type="radio" name="baget" id="two" />
<input type="radio" name="baget" id="three" />

<h1>Загрузите картинку</h1>
<input type="file" /><br />
<div class="picture">
  <img class="upload" src="" alt="" />
</div>

<h1>Выберите багет</h1>
<label for="one"></label>
<label for="two"></label>
<label for="three"></label>

<button class="clear">Очистить</button>
```

Конечно, чтобы это всё смотрелось красиво, у багетов должны быть одинаковой толщины края (эту толщину нужно указать в качестве padding'а блоку с картинкой).

Также **важный момент**: `<input type="radio" />` не случайно отделены от своих лейблов и размещены НАД блоком с картиной - только в таком случае будет работать css-конструкция :checked ~ .picture

Comment: А как быть с соотношением сторон?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, никак - любые картинки можно загружать. попробуйте :) у блока нет ни ширины, ни высоты, только padding, позволяющий обрамлять картинку в багет

Comment: Попробовал - не получилось. Попробуйте слишком узкую. Скорее всего паддинги надо вычислять, в зависимости от соотношения сторон картинки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, что значит "слишком"? предполагается, что люди будут загружать какие-то нормальные изображения, а не узкие полоски. я имею в виду, что здесь не важно, горизонтальные картинки или вертикальные - в этом плюс решения

Comment: Решение хорошее, но не учитывает соотношение сторон. Уже при 3:1 начинаются проблемы.

Comment: @humster_spb большое спасибо за ответ, я попробую) а если не цельные картинки будут даны, а как здесь например http://frame.ru/catalog/976/ ? Есть какие-то идеи, как из них можно сделать раму?

Comment: @ИринаПопова, к сожалению, я Вас зря обнадёжил: свойство border-image оказалось не таким гибким, как я думал - для него всё равно нужны цельные рамки, из отдельных кусочков не замостить

Comment: @humster_spb да, я сама попробовала и не получилось. в любом случае, спасибо за помощь)